# Graphical tool for avoiding header hell

Tags: software-development, visual-studio

I'm trying to modify an existing C++ application, and I end up in header hell:
In my newly created *.h file, I need to add an attribute to my new class, this new attribute being of the type "Timer", defined in "Timer.h".

This means that I need to add `#include "Timer.h"` at the beginning of my header file, but when I do that, I get error messages, referring to the file (don't laugh) `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\cwctype`, as if I've messed up a central file, just by adding a reference to a file, not even closely related to that central file, in other words, I've arrived in header hell :-)

The software I'm now working on, is very new, and there's here the mentality "As long as it works, it's OK", so nobody ever cared about the quality/readability/maintainability/..., so when a new developer arrives (like me), it's easy to fall into the header problem.

So my question: does anybody know about a graphical tool, which can read Visual Studio projects/solutions, read their `#include` directives, and from that, make a graph of those, so that in case of the mentioned problems, I can see what's the best way to avoid the mentioned problems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) which provided an advanced dependency graph tool integrated to VS

[image: Generating a graph from the Dependency Structure Matrix of a dependency cycle between some projects]

[image: A generated graph of dependencies between some projects]

You have also many [features](https://www.cppdepend.com/features) to understand the existing code base and a powerful [code query language](https://www.cppdepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax) to query your code like a database.